# How to find namespace for WFS request 1.1.0?

Tags: wfs

I am trying to do a GetFeature request to this  [WFS Server (GetCapabilities)](http://geoweb1.digistadtdo.de/OWSServiceProxy/baustellen.ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities), but unable to find the argument for `TYPENAME` and thus  get this error:

**msWFSGetFeature(): WFS server error. Incomplete WFS request: TYPENAME parameter missing**

A [DescribeFeatureType](http://geoweb1.digistadtdo.de/OWSServiceProxy/baustellen.ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType) request also works, but attempting to do the GetFeature request with the `<element name="Baustellen_aktuell>` does not seem to work in this format:

http://geoweb1.digistadtdo.de/OWSServiceProxy/baustellen.ows?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Baustellen_aktuell&MAXFEATURES=5&OUTPUTFORMAT=text/javascript

How can I find the appropriate namespace for the `TYPENAME` argument from the XML responses of the GetCapabilities or DescribeFeatureType requests?

Comment: The typename is as advertised in the GetCapabilities response, so `Baustellen_aktuell` and `Baustellen_geplant`  they have no namespace prefix, so their namespace would be the default namespace.

Comment: It appears from the name that there is some sort of proxy configured for the underlying service `http://asgeow02n.stadtdo.de/gisserver/service?map=/gdi_dienste/baustellen/baustellen_internet.map&` and my guess is that it is expecting some sort of case sensitive spelling for the TYPENAME parameter (that's against the WFS specification for parameter names), so I think that the service  is in error not your request

Comment: If the parameter value was incorrect you'd expect a different error  response along the lines of `msWFSGetFeature(): WFS server error. TYPENAME 'ms:Baustellen_aktuellType' doesn't exist in this server.  Please check the capabilities and reformulate your request.`

Comment: Thanks, I also suspect the problem this proxy is behind a firewall since the URL itself cannot be accessed at all. The only odd part is that the GetCapabilities and DescribeFeatureType are also listed with this proxy in the GetCapabilities request but they do return a proper response